# File System Filter Driver - Deny file creation

Tags: windows, filesystems, driver, windows-kernel, filter-driver

I created a file system filter driver.

My driver filters IRP_MJ_CREATE and prints the file name.

```
NTSTATUS DispatchCreate(__in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, __in PIRP Irp)
{
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;

    DbgPrint("DispatchCreate() : %wZ\n", &FileObject->FileName;)

    return DispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

This works fine.

And now I want to get Access Denied on every request to create a new file.

(If possible, 'you do not have permission.')

So I tried a few things.

First, I did the following.

```
NTSTATUS DispatchCreate(__in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, __in PIRP Irp)
{
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    ULONG Option = Stack->Parameters.Create.Options;

    if ((Option >> 24) == FILE_CREATE)
    {
        DbgPrint("DispatchCreate() : File Create Denied, %wZ, %x \n", &FileObject->FileName, Option);

        return STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION; // or any error code
    }

    return DispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

This worked fine, but it worked a bit strange.

For example, if you do not have administrator privileges, you have a little bit of a say when you try to create something in "C:\".

At this time, I don't know the FileObject may be deleted normally.

So I made the following changes.

```
NTSTATUS DispatchCreate(__in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, __in PIRP Irp)
{
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    ULONG Option = Stack->Parameters.Create.Options;

    if ((Option >> 24) == FILE_CREATE)
    {
        DbgPrint("DispatchCreate() : File Create Denied, %wZ, %x \n", &FileObject->FileName, Option);

        Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION;
        return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
    }

    return DispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

However, a slightly different error message occurs.

I want it to behave exactly the same as when "Access Denied" occurs because I do not have normal privileges.

And there is another question.

Unlike other Dispatch routines, `IRP_MJ_CREATE` and `IRP_MJ_CLOSE` do not need     `IoCompleteRequest()`.

I confirmed that the handle was returned normally even if I only had the following part. (In user mode.)

```
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
```

Thank you for reading.

Please answer about my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need deny some request in filter - not need pass it to attached device - you need yourself set error status and complete `IRP`

```
Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
IofCompleteRequest(Irp);// !!!
return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED; // ! not Irp->IoStatus.Status - you can not access Irp after call IofCompleteRequest
```

> Unlike other Dispatch routines, IRP_MJ_CREATE and IRP_MJ_CLOSE do not
>   need IoCompleteRequest().

of course this is absolute false. every Irp must be completed by call `IofCompleteRequest`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I solved the problem.

However, when I first created a simple driver for practice, the `CreateDispatch()` and `CloseDispatch()` routines confirmed that the user mode program normally grabs the handle even if I just `return STATUS_SUCCESS`;.

Can you explain why?

Comment: @SlayerBae - you return control from driver. create/close have no output parameters (create have status block, but user can not check it). but irp still not destroyed. this like memory allocation - you can allocate  and then not free memory(and not use it more) and all will be worked look like ok, except memory leak.

Comment: more serious will be if you not complete another irp. say read for buffered io - data will be not copied to user buffer. if asynchronous io - apc or iocp packet will be not queued. when thread exit system check - are irp exist associated with thread - if still exist (like for create/close not finished) thread can hang on exit(wait when irp completed) as result process also never exit.  system not shutdown/reboot. not complete irp - very serious error, more than memory leak. and this can be visible long time after only

Comment: thank you.

Some examples I have not used `IoCompleteRequest()`.

I was wondering why the examples would not be completed, but the question was answered. Thank you.

Comment: I am looking to block execution of certain files. Can someone help?

Comment: @abhiarora - block execution - faster look for `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine[Ex]`

Comment: Thanks. Can we use wsdk from driver?

Comment: @abhiarora - *wsdk* ? you mean windows sdk ? but this is only headers and lib files. use you can what is exported from *ntoskrnl.exe* (primary) and another kernel modules

Comment: Yes. I meant windows sdk. Actually I am trying to make an application which has firewall, block file creation, file execution. The configuration will be read from a json file.

Comment: I know Linux and I know we can't use c user space functions in kernel modules. Can you help with windows? I didn't get your last statement.

Comment: @abhiarora - i say that you can call only exported api from kernel modules (*we can't use c user space functions in kernel modules* - this i and mean).

Comment: @rbmm I have found file execution can be blocked via registry too. Can you comment on difference between API suggested by you and registery method?

Comment: @abhiarora - how concrete via registry ? by hardcoded name ? but what if name changed ? by extension ? but this is not selective (you say disable all .exe from run) ? and anyway have no effect to `CreateProcess` api. really, if you want block by file content - FS filter or PS callbacks.